# Is this a valid implementation of composition in Go?

Tags: go, composition

Is this valid composition? Or there are other solutions?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type Person struct{ name string }

type Swimmer struct{}

func (s *Swimmer) Swim(name string) {
    fmt.Println(strings.Join([]string{
        name,
        " is swimming",
    }, ""))
}

type IronMan struct {
    person  Person
    swimmer Swimmer
}

func (i *IronMan) Swim() {
    i.swimmer.Swim(i.person.name)
}

func main() {
    ironMan := IronMan{
        person:  Person{"Mariottide"},
        swimmer: Swimmer{},
    }

    ironMan.Swim()
}
```

Comment: Just because something is syntactically valid doesn't mean it is idiomatic. Please do not try to model your code like you would in traditional OOP.

Comment: I am looking for idiomatic solutions. I know only traditional OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go has `struct` embedding:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct{ name string }

func (p *Person) Talk(message string) {
    fmt.Printf("%s says: %s\n", p.name, message)
}

type Swimmer struct {
    Person
}

func (s *Swimmer) Swim() {
    fmt.Printf("%s is swimming\n", s.name)
}

type IronMan struct {
    Swimmer
}

func main() {
    ironMan := IronMan{Swimmer{Person{"Mariottide"}}}

    ironMan.Swim()
    ironMan.Talk("Hey")
}
```

Comment: IronMan is also Runner and Cyclist. With your solution you must pass three time person? IronMan{Swimmer{Person{"Mariottide"},Runner{Person{"Mariottide"}, ...}

Comment: Yes. You can create factory for that. This is how golang composition works. Check this article http://hackthology.com/object-oriented-inheritance-in-go.html